# How a string size is calculated in python?

Tags: python

How a string size is calculated in python? I tried a below code:

```
s = "test"
s.__sizeof__()
53

bytes(s, "utf-8").__sizeof__()
37

bytes(s, "utf-16").__sizeof__()
43

bytes(s, "utf-32").__sizeof__()
53
```

How does python calculate the size for a string? Even if I consider, utf-8 encoding, any character can take anywhere between 1 byte to 4 bytes. Even if I consider the maximum size of 4 bytes per character, a string of 4 characters should take around 16 bytes, but `__sizeof__` function shows bytes ranging from 37 bytes to 53 bytes based on the encoding chosen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python : Get size of string in bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686701/python-get-size-of-string-in-bytes)

Comment: This may answer your question: [sizeof(string) not equal to string length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38749126/5893316) or a more generic Q/A about this topic: [How do I determine the size of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/449560/5893316)

Answer (score 0):

`__sizeof__` calculates the size of the underlying [*Python object*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof), and these objects are more complicated than the literal bytes that comprise a string.

An empty `bytes` object is 33 bytes:

```
>>> b''.__sizeof__()
33
```

`"test"` in UTF-8 is exactly [4 bytes wide](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#test), so you get:

```
bytes(s, "utf-8").__sizeof__()
37 == b''.__sizeof__() + 4
```

The other encodings seem to encode some characters with more than 2 and 4 bytes, respectively, so you get sizes greater than `33 + 2 * 4 = 41` and `33 + 4 * 4 = 49`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just print the following commands, you will see that `__sizeof__` is bringing you the size result of each result below:

```
>>> s='test'
>>> bytes(s,'utf-8').__sizeof__()
37
>>> bytes(s,'utf-8')
b'test'
>>> bytes(s,'utf-16')
b'\xff\xfet\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00'
>>> bytes(s,'utf-32')
b'\xff\xfe\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00'
```

The way you wrote your code `__sizeof__` is bringing you the size of each one of those lines:

- b'test'
- b'\xff\xfet\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00'
- b'\xff\xfe\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00'

And not the size of converted encoding string size.